# dynamic wsdl creation by spring-ws error

Tags: java, web-services, spring, wsdl, spring-ws

I want to create my wsdl by spring-ws automatically and I inserted the code below to my app context file, but I got the error;

"Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [dynamic-wsdl]"

what does that mean and what can I do? tnx

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org   /schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="payloadMapping"
       class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="inferenceEndPoint" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref local="validatingInterceptor" />
            <ref local="payLoadInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="payLoadInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" />

<bean id="validatingInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <description>
        This interceptor validates the incoming
        message contents
        according to the 'Request.xsd' XML
        Schema file.
    </description>
    <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="inferenceEndPoint" class="com.mywebsite.ws.web.InferenceEndPoint">
    <property name="messageService" ref="messageService" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageService" class="com.mywebsite.ws.service.MessageService">
    <property name="inferenceService" ref="inferenceService" />
</bean>

<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd" />
</bean>

  <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="mtwsdl"
    portTypeName="mtWS"
    locationUri="http://localhost:8080/mws/">
<sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd" />
   </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
<bean id="inferenceService" class="com.mywebsite.ws.im.InferenceService">
    <property name="webServiceConfiguration" ref="playerConfiguration" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="inferenceConfig" class="com.mywebsite.ws.im.InferenceService"> 
    <constructor-arg ref="playerConfiguration"/> </bean> -->

<!-- ~~~~~~~ Application beans ~~~~~~~ -->
<bean id="playerConfiguration"
    class="com.mywebsite.ws.configuration.WebServiceConfiguration"
    init-method="init">
    <property name="playerConfigXml" value="/WEB-INF/config/webserviceconfiguration.xml" />
    <property name="executingPathResource" value="/WEB-INF" />
    <property name="developmentMode" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at the class path and also server run time path, I think you may have both (spring-ws 1.5.x and spring-ws 2.x) version's of jar files either in the compile/run time path. If that is not the case clean up the both class and run time path and add only spring-ws 2.x jar files.

As for the differences, when spring framework name space handler (WebServicesNamespaceHandler) encounters (**dynamic-wsdl** tag in **spring context** file), It will register a (DynamicWsdlBeanDefinitionParser) bean with all the properties specified in the dynamic wsdl tag. It is essentially same as you registering (DefaultWsdl11Definition) bean in spring context.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the first section of your appcontext where you define namespaces:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: still same error, while auto creating wsdl what is difference between using the approach above and using something like this   <bean id="wsdlGeneration" 
  class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition"> 
  <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
   <property name="portTypeName" value="MyWS" />
   <property name="locationUri" value="/mws/" />
   <property name="targetNamespace" 
   </bean>

Comment: Refresh, clean, redeploy, you cannot have the same error, your schema definitions were wrong and these are the right ones. (Reproduced your exact error and after replacing the schema definitions they disappeared) - what IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse, No it didnt work same errors, please check that I have edited my config file above, you can see all the file above

Comment: Do you have Spring WS jars on your classpath? Using Maven? Have something like this in your pom.xml?: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.ws</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I dont use maven, I have jars on my classpath, actually my web service works well.this was a old project that I have updated, but the wsdl seemed not working with soapUI, so I wanted to create it from scratch..

Comment: Which spring-ws jar you have exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest to use Maven.  The error you are getting is due to a missing library.  In Maven you should have an entry like the following.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```